# configuring netzke javascript code using inheritance (defining js code in a parent class with parameters)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, netzke

I have two netzke grid components with action columns (and more on the way). The action columns are nearly identical, depending on the type. The only difference is the action to be done when clicking the action-button.

So what I want to do is define a new grid component, that has all the shared parts, including the javascript, and then configure the javascript (set the parameters/context) in the inheriting classes.

So first, my class would look as follows:

```
class CpPoles < Netzke::Basepack::Grid
  include Netzke::Basepack::ActionColumn

  .. snipped ..    

  column :actions do |c|
    c.type = :action
    c.actions = [
        {name: :locate_on_map, tooltip: "show on map", icon: :map_marker},
    ]
  end

  js_configure do |c|
    c.on_locate_on_map = <<-JS
      function(record){
        Map.zoomToFeature('cp_poles', record.raw[0]);
      }
    JS
  end
end
```

And in my other class it looks identical, except for the layer_name:

```
  js_configure do |c|
    c.on_locate_on_map = <<-JS
      function(record){
        Map.zoomToFeature('markerpoles', record.raw[0]);
      }
    JS
  end
```

So I introduced a new grid class, which contains all the shared configuration, and defines the action as well:

```
  js_configure do |c|
    c.on_locate_on_map = <<-JS
      function(record){
        Map.zoomToFeature(this.layer_name, record.raw[0]);
      }
    JS
  end
```

Now I only have to set the `this.layer_name`. Dead-easy I thought. In my class `CpPole` I can now write

```
class CpPoles < Netzke::MyApplication::Grid

  js_configure do |c|
    c.layer_name = 'cp_poles'
  end

end
```

But that does not work :( So I tried with a mixin, and on the `initComponent` set `this.layer_name`, but that also did not work. I am afraid that the `this` in my shared grid is not the same as the `this` in my CpPole class, yet the `on_locate_map` does work.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I solved it differently, to my base class I added a method

```
def self.set_action_methods(layer_name)
  js_configure do |c|
    c.on_locate_on_map = <<-JS
      function(record){
        Map.zoomToFeature('#{layer_name}', record.raw[0]);
      }
    JS
  end
end
```

which adds all the action methods (in my code it adds more than just the one).

So my derived class gets really simple, I just need to specify the configure block

```
class Markerpoles < Netzke::MyBaseGrid

  def configure(c)
    super
    c.model = 'Markerpole'
    c.columns = [
        :name,
        {name: :location, flex: 1},
        {name: :comments, flex: 1},
        {name: 'markerpole_material__label', text: "Material"}
    ]
  end

  set_action_methods('markerpoles')
end
```

Looks pretty nice. Not sure if there is a better solution?